# Mocked Async Method in xUnit-Test returns always null

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, moq, xunit

I have a ASP.NET WebAPI 2 project and I am trying to add unit-testing with xunit and moq.

This is my Get-Method in my Controller:

```
public class SiteController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ISite _siteSrv;

    public SiteController( ISite siteSrv )
    {
        _siteSrv = siteSrv;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get( int id )
    {
        //reading current user login id and user roles [...]

        // getting data from SiteService, which I try to mock
        var site = await _siteSrv.Get( id, userLoginId.Value, roles );

        //converting it into a model [...]

        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

And my SiteService Get method:

```
public async Task<Site> Get( int id, long userLoginId, string[] roles )
{
    //...doing some stuff
    // and returning the data
    return await _context.Sites
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync( s => s.SiteId == id );
}
```

This is my Test-Method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Verify_GetId_Method_Returns_OkResult_ForAdmin()
{
    int siteId = 1;
    long userLoginId = 1;
    string role = "Admin";

    // fake site
    var site = new Site()
    {
        SiteId = 1,
        SiteName = "Site1"
    };

    // mocking the SiteService
    var mockSite = new Mock<ISite>();
    // setting up the Get-Method returning the fake site asynchronously
    mockSite.Setup( s => s.Get( siteId, userLoginId, new string[] { role } ) )
        .ReturnsAsync( site );

    // faking HttpContext
    using ( new FakeHttpContext.FakeHttpContext() )
    {
        // current logged in user
        HttpContext.Current.User = CurrentUserTestData.GetAccount( 
            userLoginId, role );

        // the SiteController with the mocked SiteService
        var controller = new SiteController( mockSite.Object );
        // setting Request
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        controller.Request.Properties.Add( 
            HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,
            new HttpConfiguration() );

        // calling the async Get method of the controller
        var result = await controller.Get( siteId );
        // !! result is always NULL !!

        Assert.NotNull( result ); // FAIL
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It might be the argument matcher isn't matching your `string[]` of roles, try it with `It.IsAny<string[]` if that works you've isolated the problem and can capture that argument in a callback if you need to verify the correct role was passed.

Comment: @JSteward That was it. Thank you. Now I understand It.IsAny :) I changed all 3 parameters with It.Is and it works. Yesterday I finally wrote a FakeSiteService to work but this is a much better solution. Could you please write this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that the argument matcher is looking at your arguments and trying to match them to what was provided in the `Setup`. It does this by using the default equality which for arrays means reference equality. So for your `string[]` of roles you won't match that argument and your `Setup` will never be matched and you'll get a null result. Changing your setup to allow any array of roles will allow the matcher to succeed.

```
mockSite.Setup( s => s.Get( siteId, userLoginId, It.IsAny<string[]>() ) )
    .ReturnsAsync( site );
```